# Find page number by row ID in paged list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to determine a page numer (in paged list), that contains row with given ID?

Comment: We need far more information to try to answer this. What exactly do you want?

Comment: Paged list means that I retrieve information partialy using SKIP and TAKE statements. For example, I have 100 rows divided into 10 pages. So if I want to get second page, I write: SELECT * FROM rows SKIP ((PageNumber - 1) * 10) TAKE (10); // where PageNumber is 2. Now I want to find out what is page numer for row with ID 55.

Comment: T-sql does not have SKIP or TAKE.

Comment: Version for T-SQL: SELECT TOP (10) Id, NumberField, DateField, ROW_NUMBER() as _SortRow FROM rows WHERE _SortRow > (PageNumber - 1) * 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work in T-SQL if you make sure the ORDER BY is accurate for what you're sorting by:

```
DECLARE @RowId INT = 55
    , @PageSize INT = 10;

DECLARE @Data TABLE
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , Value INT
)

INSERT @Data
SELECT
    CAST(V.number AS INT)
FROM master..spt_values V
WHERE V.[type] = 'P'
    AND CAST(V.number AS INT) BETWEEN 1 AND 100

;WITH RankedData AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY D.Value) AS Row
        , D.Id
    FROM
        @Data D
)
SELECT 
    (SELECT Row FROM RankedData WHERE Id = @RowId) / @PageSize
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Foo as table ( FooId int identity, Bar varchar(16) )
insert into @Foo ( Bar ) values ( 'this' ), ( 'is' ), ( 'some' ), ( 'sample' ), ( 'data' ), ( 'eh?' )

declare @PageSize int = 3

-- Display the page numbers.  Note that there must be an explicit order.
select FooId, Bar, ( RN + @PageSize - 1 ) / @PageSize as Page
  from (
  select FooId, Bar, Row_Number() over ( order by Bar ) as RN
    from @Foo
    ) as Janet

-- Retrieve a single page number based on a   FooId .
select FooId, Bar, ( RN + @PageSize - 1 ) / @PageSize as Page
  from (
  select FooId, Bar, Row_Number() over ( order by Bar ) as RN
    from @Foo
    ) as Janet
  where FooId = 3
```